# Why does Excel generate my CSV in a random fashion (PHP)?

Tags: php, excel, csv, export

I am writing data to a `CSV` using `PHP`, but `Excel` seems to arrange my data into random rows. Here is the code:

```
   <?php
    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Titles.csv"');

    // do not cache the file
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');

    // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');


    $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];
    $copytext = $_POST['copytext'];
    $brand = $_POST['brand'];

    $KeywordArray = explode(',', $keywords);
    $CopyTextArray = explode(',', $copytext);
    $BrandArray = explode(',', $brand);

    $RandomCopy = array_rand($CopyTextArray, 3);
    $RandomBrand = array_rand($BrandArray, 3);

    echo "Keyword,Title\n";

    foreach ($KeywordArray as $element) {
        echo $element.",";
        echo $element." ";
        echo $CopyTextArray[$RandomCopy[rand(0,2)]]." ";
        echo $BrandArray[$RandomBrand[rand(0,2)]]."\n";
         }

    ?>
```

And here is an example of what I mean (please note that row 12 is how I want the data to be organized:

**Example:**

[image: example]

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code by doing some changes accordingly

```
            $fileName = 'abc';
            $file = DIR_DOWNLOAD.$fileName.'.csv' ;
            $mask = basename($file);
            $fp = fopen($file, "w");
            $feilds = array('product_id','boost','status');
            fputcsv($fp, $feilds);

            foreach($mappingResults->rows as $row){
                fputcsv($fp, $row);
            }
            fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ",");
            fclose($fp);   
            header('Content-Type:text/csv');
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . ($mask ? $mask : basename($file)) . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
```

Here You can change `$mappingResults->rows` to your array name `$KeywordArray`.

Hope this would be helpful.